# "Phone charging slowly" but I'm not TRYING to charge it!

Tags: 8.1, usb

Often, when I plug my phone into my PC to transfer files, I get the 'Phone charging slowly' message. OK, I wasn't trying to charge it, but I can handle the message.

The problem is, that invariably, when I get the message, the phone/PC fail to connect at all.

---

Partial/tentative answer: I think it may depend *how* charged the phone is. After leaving the phone charging for a while, I tried unplugging/plugging and it connected.

Comment: Have you connected the phone directly to a USB port or to a USB hub? Have you tried another cable / port?

Comment: @Thomas, I've got a port directly on the PC, and another one via the monitor. Both have worked and not worked in the past. Right now neither are cooperating :(

Comment: strange. I assume you're using the cable that was shipped with the phone? Thing is, your pc will always try to charge your phone and there's no way to turn that off. Have you tried disableing the notification for "slow charging" in Settings -> USB ?

Comment: @Thomas, I didn't *get* a cable with the phone. It's a Lumia 735 and the charger cable is hard-wired into the plug. I did try disabling the notification, but it didn't change anything. However, see my answer below.

Comment: I have actually tried this now with 6 different USB cables, hoping to discover a consistency. The only consistency is it fails to work and always says CHARGING SLOWLY.

Answer (score 1):

This happens with me a lot when I'm debugging an app on my phone. Simply restarting the phone solves the issue. This is some driver issue in Windows Phone 8/8.1

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of your USB cable. Cable that comes with your phone from your company is able to perform high speed operations including charging. So that cable usually performs charging as well as data transfer. So if the cable speed is slow for charging then it will show"charging slowly"... And in that case you won't be even able to transfer the data. It happens with the damaged cable. So I would suggest you to change it ASAP.